# Access to pixel value depth map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, kinect

im trying to access to pixel value of depth map, using kinect, openni and opencv. im using this code

```
Mat depth;
VideoCapture capture1(CV_CAP_OPENNI);
capture1.grab();
capture1.retrieve(depth,CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP);
imshow("depth",depth);

waitKey(0);
cout << depth.at<unsigned>(20,20);
system("PAUSE");
```

the program show me the depth map but when i tried to acccess to the value, produce an error. but if y put:

```
cout << depth;
```

then show me all the values.

Comment: Which version of OpenCV is this?

Answer (score 0):

Since **you didn't specified the error**, I'll give it a shot: the problem seems to be that you are trying to access elements from another `Mat`: the one you create is named `depth`, however the one referenced in the `cout` call  is named `depthshow`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html) for `CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP`, your `Mat` should have 16 bits unsigned integer data per pixel, rather than the 32-bits `unsigned int` you're trying to use. Therefore, use the following instead:

```
// uint16_t available in C++11
cout << depth.at<uint16_t>(20,20) << " millimetres";
```

or

```
// not 100% sure that all compilers produce 16 bits fields
cout << depth.at<unsigned short int>(20,20) << " millimetres";
```